# Equivalence of semidefiniteness and quadratic inequality

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

My question is about a logical equivalence in Robert Freund's lecture notes "An Introduction to Semidefinite Programming (SDP)" from MIT's OCW.

The claim is that for $Q$ an $n\times n$ real symmetric PSD matrix with factorization $M^{T}M$, $q$ an $n$ dimensional column vector, and $c$ a real number,
$$\mathcal{S} = \begin{pmatrix} 
I & Mx \\
x^{T}M^{T} & -c - q^{T}x
\end{pmatrix}$$
is PSD if and only if \begin{equation} x^{T}Qx + q^{T}x + c \leq 0. \end{equation}

I've worked out $u^{T}\mathcal{S}u$ (for $u \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$) and would like to know how the statement:
\begin{align}
u^{T}\mathcal{S}u &= \sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2+2u_{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^nu_i\sum_{j=1}^nM_{ij}x_j -(u_{n+1})^2(c+q^{T}x)\\
& \geq 0 \text{ for all $u$}
\end{align}
is equivalent to the condition on the quadratic function of $x$. I've done the computation a couple of times, but it is possible I went wrong somewhere and this is the wrong expansion of the quadratic form.

It looks like doing this by computing eigenvalues or even computing all principle minors (and showing their being non-negative is equivalent to the quadratic condition) is possible with work. I wouldn't mind knowing the "right" or easiest way to see this equivalence, but **this** question is about understanding why $u^{T}\mathcal{S}u \geq 0 \forall u$ is equivalent to $x^{T}Qx+q^{T}x + c \leq 0$.

Comment: Your $u^TSu$ is  wrong because it does not contain neither $q$ nor $c$, but it clearly should. When you get it right, you should see what value to plug in for $u$ to get the conclusion. Do not split $u$ into all separate coordinates.

Comment: Isn't this just the Schur complement?

Comment: @Michal Adamszek: thank you for the comment! You are right, I left off that term in the original, but it is now edited. I am okay with picking $u$ such that the quadratic condition holds, but how does one see that the quadratic condition implies the “quadratic form in $\mathcal{S}$” inequality for all $u$? I was hoping it would be some sort of convexity argument, but I’m having trouble seeing that (hence the expansion into the coordinate $u_i$).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo : thanks for pointing me to the Schur Complement, this provides the easiest way to show the equivalence I've seen so far.

Comment: @Lockjaw You may want to take a look at Gallier's [notes](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/schur-comp.pdf).